# Is any K3 surface of degree 8 in P^5 the complete intersection of quadrics?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, k3-surfaces

Here the base field is the field of complex numbers.

Comment: Maybe add the "k3-surfaces" tag?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Any* $K3$ surface $S$ of degree $8$ in $\mathbb{P}^5$ is contained in $3$ linearly independent quadrics. It can be seen that in the *general* case $S$ is a complete intersection of $3$ quadrics. However, there are some special cases where this is not true, but they can be completely described.

The point is that $S$ is a complete intersection of $3$ quadrics if and only if a general hyperplane section (which is a smooth curve of genus $5$) has no $g_3^1$.

You can find all details in  [Beauville, Complex Algebraic Surfaces, Chapter VIII, Example 14 and Exercise 11].